# swift game doesn't work as i want it to

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i am creating a game where random shapes fall down and each shape has  number , and that number represent the number of clicks the user has to do on the image , so the image would be removed and the score be increased by one , but i have a problem when the images are created , and when i run it some of the images work fine and when i click on it the number of times it has on it , it gets removed like i want to , but when the same image is created sometimes , when i click on it it prints out a msg that i have put "the user has not clicked on an image " which i have put in my default in my switch stattment in the touchEnded method , like so :

```
    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            switch(nodeAtPoint(location)){

            case self.circle:
                if circleCount == 1{
                    circle.removeFromParent()
                    println("score")
                    circleCount = 0
                }

            case self.rectangle:
                if rectangleCount == 2{
                    println("score")
                    rectangle.removeFromParent()
                    rectangleCount = 0
                }

            case self.square:

                    if squareCount == 3{
                    println("score")
                    square.removeFromParent()
                    squareCount = 0
                }

            case self.polygon:
                if polygonCount == 4{
                    println("score")
                    polygon.removeFromParent()
                    polygonCount = 0
                }


            default:
                println("user didnt click on an image")

        }

    }

}
```

and thats is one of the functions that displays one of the images:

```
func createRectangle(a: CGFloat){
     rectangle = SKSpriteNode()
    rectangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rectangle")
    rectangle.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
    rectangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: rectangle.size)
    rectangle.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    rectangle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    rectangle.position = CGPoint(x: a, y: self.frame.size.height)
    self.addChild(rectangle)
}
```

and there is a function that generates a random number to display the shapes randomly.

Comment: Can you edit the title to make it more telling what's wrong? I think each question here is because something is working not as expected, and `swift` you already have in tags, so this title doesn't say anything about the problem - less people will reach this question. Also refactor your question and use `.` when required, as it's hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this updated code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import Darwin

var squareCount = 0
var circleCount = 0
var rectangleCount = 0
var polygonCount = 0
var x = 0

class StartGame: SKScene {


    var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "cholkDuster")
    let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    var score = 0

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        addBackGround()
        addScoreLabel()
        //random number for the shapes
        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(initiateShapes), SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)])))
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -0.5)
    }

    func addScoreLabel(){
        scoreLabel.zPosition = 0
        self.scoreLabel.text = "0"
        self.scoreLabel.fontSize = 42
        self.scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(scoreLabel)
    }

    func addBackGround() {
        //background image
        bg.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        bg.size.width = self.frame.size.width
        bg.size.height = self.frame.size.height
        bg.zPosition = -10
        self.addChild(bg)
    }



    func initiateShapes() {

        let shapeArray = ["circle", "rectangle", "square", "polygon"]
        x = Int (arc4random_uniform(4))
        let shape = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: shapeArray[x])
        shape.name = shapeArray[x]
        shape.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
        let actualX = random(min: shape.size.height/2, max: size.width - shape.size.height/2)
        shape.position = CGPoint(x: actualX, y: size.height + shape.size.width / 2)
        shape.zPosition = 10
        addChild(shape)

        let actualDuration = random(min: CGFloat(2.0), max: CGFloat(4.0))
        let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: actualX, y: -shape.size.width / 2), duration: 5.1)
        let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        shape.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        score++
        if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
            let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if nodeAtPoint(touchLocation).name == "circle" {
                nodeAtPoint(touchLocation).removeFromParent()
            } else if nodeAtPoint(touchLocation).name == "rectangle" {
                nodeAtPoint(touchLocation).removeFromParent()
            } else if nodeAtPoint(touchLocation).name == "square" {
                nodeAtPoint(touchLocation).removeFromParent()
            } else if nodeAtPoint(touchLocation).name == "polygon"{
                nodeAtPoint(touchLocation).removeFromParent()
            } else {
                println("Nothing")
            }

            scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        }
    }

    func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
    }

    func random(#min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return random() * (max - min) + min
    }

    func randomInt(min: Int, max:Int) -> Int {
        return min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1)))
    }

}
```